# ItemSend / OnSend not triggering

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Does the OnSend Event of a Web Add-in for outlook work on the desktop outlook 2016 app?

The Addin is working well on the OWA in web browser but the Onsend event of the Addin does not trigger when the account is used in the windows outlook app. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[On send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins) Documentation clearly stated the following ...

> The on send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in Office 365, Exchange 2016 on-premises (Cumulative Update 6 or later), and Exchange 2019 on-premises (Cumulative Update 1 or later). Add-ins that use the on send feature aren't allowed in the Office Store.

Currently only Outlook on the web client is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and restart Outlook.  Worked for me.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security]
"EnableUnsafeClientMailRules"=dword:00000001
```